# prevent android app from upgrading from older versions

Tags: android, apk, upgrade, versions

We have an Android app for which we release an upgrade every few months.

We recently concluded that there are several users still running our previous versions of our app with unsupported features.

What is working out to be expensive for us is to continue adding migration for these old users who may at some point upgrade.

While we are working on a force upgrade since the recent versions, is there a way we can stop these users from upgrading from Google play?

Please help and let me know if you have any questions.